# How can I find out the size of the included packages with webpack or NPM?

Tags: npm, webpack

I attempted using the `webpack-bundle-size-analyzer` package but it doesn't seem to work. Is there an easy way to output the sizes of the included packages in a webpack project?

Alternatively if there's a way to output the size of package.json packages with NPM that would be cool as well.

Comment: Did you find any alternative to `webpack-bundle-size-analyzer`?

Comment: I can get the info by
npm install -g webpack-bundle-size-analyzer
webpack --json | webpack-bundle-size-analyzer
But there is not much info. everything is in SELF

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put the run script inside `package.json`? It worked after I put it inside package.json like so:

```
...
"scripts": {
 ...
 "analyzer": "webpack --json | webpack-bundle-size-analyzer"
}
...
```

then in the shell do `npm run analyzer`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to investigate the size of packages individually, you can use this tool -  https://cost-of-modules.herokuapp.com

It'll tell you what the peformance characteristics (min, min +gzipped) of any npm package would be if you were to add it to your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Webpack Bundle Analyzer](https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer).

It represents bundle content as convenient interactive zoomable treemap.